# How do I get the aggregate calendar to show in Web Part

Tags: calendar

I created an aggregate calendar and added the web part to homepage, however, it's showing calendar, but not the aggregate calendar items, i have to click on the title URL and then it takes me to the aggregate calendar, I want to have them visible in the calendar that appears on the homepage without having to click the title, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me. If you edit the web part and select "calendar" view (I know, even if it is already showing the calendar) and apply it should update with the roll-up.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird, still not working. I have a number of times trying to add web part, it may be due to that. thank you